# DoesNotExist at /nuevo/ Profile matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, python-requests

sorry I'm quite new to Django and Python, doing a school project, I was doing a default login with python, it creates the users and makes a login, so far so good. When I log in with the admin I can enter "html.html" without problems and the view runs and makes the queries in the database, the problem is when I log in with a different profile than the admin, I get this message

DoesNotExist at /nuevo/

Profile matching query does not exist.

Request Method:     GET

I think the problem is with this query

```
query = Profile.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
```

What I wanted was for the user who is logged in to send me to work on their database, I don't know what else to do :(
these are my models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='batman.png')
    equip = models.CharField(max_length=1500,default=0)
    pokemon1 = models.CharField(max_length=1500,default=0)
    pokemon2 = models.CharField(max_length=1500,default=0)
    pokemon3 = models.CharField(max_length=1500,default=0)
    pokemon4 = models.CharField(max_length=1500,default=0)
    pokemon5 = models.CharField(max_length=1500,default=0)
    pokemon6 = models.CharField(max_length=1500,default=0)
    

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Perfil de {self.user.username}'



class Post(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='posts')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}:{self.content}'
```

my views

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib import messages
import requests
import random
from .models import Post, Profile
from django.contrib.auth import *


def feed(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()

    context = {'posts': post}
    return render(request, 'social/feed.html',context)



def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            messages.success(request, f'Usuario {username} creado')
            return redirect('feed')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'social/register.html', context)

def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'social/profile.html')


def index(request):

    return render(request, 'social/index.html')



def nuevo(request):
    #Funcion de peticion para saber si el perfil tiene ya un equipo, si no lo genera.
    
    query = Profile.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
    a = query.equip
    Contador = 2
    if a == "0":
        #Pikachu
        url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25"
        response = requests.get(url)
        content = response.json()
        poke_data = []
        poke_data2 = []
        #Guardado de pikachu
        query.pokemon1 = url
        query.save()
        ###################
        single_poke = {
            'name':content['name'],
            'id':content['id'],
            'sprites':content['sprites']['front_default'],
            'types':content['types'][0]['type']['name'],
            'types2':'-'
            }
        poke_data.append(single_poke)


        for i in range(2):
            get_poke = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"
            poke = 0
            poke = random.randint(1, 500)
            url = get_poke + str(poke)
            response = requests.get(url)
            content = response.json()
            
                        #Guardado de pokemonURL en la base de datos
            #query = Profile.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
            
            
            if Contador == 2:
                query.pokemon2 = url
                query.save()
                Contador= Contador + 1
            elif Contador == 3:
                query.pokemon3 = url
                query.save()
                Contador= Contador + 1
            else:
                query.pokemon4 = url
                query.save()
                
            
            ############################################

            if (len(content['types']) == 1):
                single_poke = {
                    'name':content['name'],
                    'id':content['id'],
                    'sprites':content['sprites']['front_default'],
                    'types':content['types'][0]['type']['name'],
                    'types2':'-'
                }
                poke_data.append(single_poke)
            else:
                single_poke = {
                    'name':content['name'],
                    'id':content['id'],
                    'sprites':content['sprites']['front_default'],
                    'types':content['types'][0]['type']['name'],
                    'types2':content['types'][1]['type']['name']
                }
                poke_data.append(single_poke)


        for i in range(3):
            get_poke2 = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"
            poke2 = 0
            poke2 = random.randint(1, 500)
            url2 = get_poke2 + str(poke2)
            response2 = requests.get(url2)
            content2 = response2.json()

            #Guardado de pokemonURL en la base de datos
            #query = Profile.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
            
            
            if Contador == 4:
                query.pokemon4 = url2
                query.save()
                Contador= Contador + 1
            elif Contador == 5:
                query.pokemon5 = url2
                query.save()
                Contador= Contador + 1
            else:
                query.pokemon6 = url2
                query.save()
                
            
            ############################################
        #    print(len(content2['types']))        

            if (len(content2['types']) == 1):
                single_poke2 = {
                    'name':content2['name'],
                    'id':content2['id'],
                    'sprites':content2['sprites']['front_default'],
                    'types':content2['types'][0]['type']['name'],
                    'types2':'-'
                }
                poke_data2.append(single_poke2)
            else:
                single_poke2 = {
                    'name':content2['name'],
                    'id':content2['id'],
                    'sprites':content2['sprites']['front_default'],
                    'types':content2['types'][0]['type']['name'],
                    'types2':content2['types'][1]['type']['name']
                }
                poke_data2.append(single_poke2)

        #Guardando equipo completo 
        equipoCompleto = []
        equipoCompleto = poke_data + poke_data2
        query.equip = equipoCompleto
        query.save()
        
        return render(request,'social/nuevo.html',{'poke_data':poke_data,'poke_data2':poke_data2})
    else:
        P1 = query.pokemon1
        P2 = query.pokemon2
        P3 = query.pokemon3
        P4 = query.pokemon4
        P5 = query.pokemon5
        P6 = query.pokemon6
        url = P1
        response = requests.get(url)
        content = response.json()
        poke_data = []
        poke_data2 = []

        single_poke = {
            'name':content['name'],
            'id':content['id'],
            'sprites':content['sprites']['front_default'],
            'types':content['types'][0]['type']['name'],
            'types2':'-'
            }
    #  print(single_poke)
        poke_data.append(single_poke)
        Contador = 2


        for i in range(2):
            if Contador == 2:
                url = P2
                
                Contador= Contador + 1
            else:
                url = P3
            
                Contador= Contador + 1

          
            response = requests.get(url)
          
            content = response.json()
          
            if (len(content['types']) == 1):
                single_poke = {
                    'name':content['name'],
                    'id':content['id'],
                    'sprites':content['sprites']['front_default'],
                    'types':content['types'][0]['type']['name'],
                    'types2':'-'
                }
                poke_data.append(single_poke)
               
            else:
                single_poke = {
                    'name':content['name'],
                    'id':content['id'],
                    'sprites':content['sprites']['front_default'],
                    'types':content['types'][0]['type']['name'],
                    'types2':content['types'][1]['type']['name']
                }
                poke_data.append(single_poke)


        for i in range(3):
            
            if Contador == 4:
                url2 = P4
               
                Contador= Contador + 1
            elif Contador == 5:
                url2 = P5
              
                Contador= Contador + 1
            else:
                url2 = P6
              
            response2 = requests.get(url2)
            content2 = response2.json()

            if (len(content2['types']) == 1):
                single_poke2 = {
                    'name':content2['name'],
                    'id':content2['id'],
                    'sprites':content2['sprites']['front_default'],
                    'types':content2['types'][0]['type']['name'],
                    'types2':'-'
                }
                poke_data2.append(single_poke2)
            else:
                single_poke2 = {
                    'name':content2['name'],
                    'id':content2['id'],
                    'sprites':content2['sprites']['front_default'],
                    'types':content2['types'][0]['type']['name'],
                    'types2':content2['types'][1]['type']['name']
                }
                poke_data2.append(single_poke2)

        return render(request,'social/nuevo.html',{'poke_data':poke_data,'poke_data2':poke_data2})
```

my html page

```
    {% extends 'social/layout.html'%}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href="{% static '/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% if poke_data %}
    <center>    
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div id="contenidos">
                {% for poke_data in poke_data %}
                    <div class="poke-card">
                        <div  class="img-container">
                            <img  class="poke-img" src={{poke_data.sprites}}>
                        </div>
                        <div>{{ poke_data.name}}</div>
                        <div>ID:{{poke_data.id}}</div>
                        <div>{{poke_data.types}}</div> 
                        <div>{{poke_data.types2}}</div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
    <center>    
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div id="contenidos">
                {% for poke_data2 in poke_data2 %}
                    <div class="poke-card">
                        <div  class="img-container"><img  class="poke-img" src={{poke_data2.sprites}}></div>
                        <div>{{ poke_data2.name}}</div>
                        <div>ID:{{poke_data2.id}}</div>
                        <div>{{poke_data2.types}}</div>
                        <div>{{poke_data2.types2}}</div>
                    </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

settings

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-l^#a!=5a)fewvqnf!#ao(sp08uec9qbzx84zsxw@sqo5nh@+sn'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

#borrar por si acaso
STATICFILES_DIRS=['D:/ProFinalWWW/poke_proyect/poke/static']
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'poke.apps.PokeConfig',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'poke_proyect.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['D:/ProFinalWWW/poke_proyect/poke/templates/social'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'poke_proyect.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'ind'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Sorry for the mess in my code, I'm just learning to program, I hope you can help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```py
query = Profile.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
```

This query is not doing what you think it’s doing. You have 2 relevant tables here (Profile and User). They both have `pk`’s and they are, for all intents and purposes, unrelated. You’ve added a OneToOneField which creates a relationship between the tables. The query actually ends up being simpler since you can check the Profile’s user and see if it matches the request.user like so:

```py
query = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Oh I understand, I'll try, thank you very much. However, what is not clear to me is that with the super user admin if the query worked but with the normal user it did not

Comment: It worked, thank you very much: D